# Reinstall NuGet packages for ASP.NET Website outside Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, msbuild, nuget

I have ASP.NET website which does not have .csproj file (it's not web application), only .sln file. In root is packages.config having several NuGet packages defined.

Calling `nuget restore .\packages.config -PackagesDirectory .\packages` downloads packages to `packages` folder, but `bin` folder is empty.

`nuget update` requires .csproj.

If I call build of website in a command line it will throw an error that DLLs were not found. If I keep `bin\*.refresh` it does not work either.

Thank you

Comment: Building the project restores the NuGet packages by default. If that is not working, then you can add the references to those packages in solution explorer. Alternatively, you can Create a new project and choose ASP.NET Web Application and copy everything to that project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a `.refresh` file for each of the packages you expect to be copied to the `bin` directory.

For example, we have a custom build of `MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC2` in one of our web sites.

### packages.config

```
<package id="Mvc2" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net35" />
<package id="MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC2.Core" version="4.6.18.1" targetFramework="net35" />
```

### /Bin Folder

```
System.Web.Mvc.dll.refresh
MvcSiteMapProvider.dll.refresh
```

> **NOTE:** It may be tricky to get your source control provider to recognize these. Make sure they are there when you clone your project to a clean directory.

#### System.Web.Mvc.dll.refresh

```
..\..\packages\Mvc2.2.0.1\lib\net35\System.Web.Mvc.dll
```

#### MvcSiteMapProvider.dll.refresh

```
..\..\packages\MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC2.Core.4.6.18.1\lib\net35\MvcSiteMapProvider.dll
```

You may need to adjust the number of `..\` in your project depending on the folder structure, but this is what we have that restores successfully.

Comment: It works now. One tricky thing was that I called only "aspnet_compiler" which ignored "*.refresh" files, and thus it kept failing get NuGet packages. Now I call "msbuild SolutionFile.sln" and then "aspnet_compiler" and it does the thing. Thank you.